# Promise in typescript - es6-promise type not available

Tags: typescript, types, promise

I want to use `new Promise()` in my typescript. Promise is not known form TS so I'm trying to install it `npm install @type/es6-promise --save-dev` but it says `Not found : @type/es6-promise`. How come?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/es6-promise

Comment: it is `@types` not `@type`. is it just a typo or you gave the wrong command?

Comment: please see, if this solves your problem. import { Promise } from 'es6-promise'; You might need to install es6-promise using npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is

```
npm install @types/es6-promise --save-dev
```

You have a typo in your command.